# how to make plus math with variable javascript

Tags: javascript

i was planning to add the value of `luas_lingkaran` and `luas_persegi` in variable `luas_total`,but it comes up with showing the value of `luas_lingkaran` and `luas_persegi` not adding each value

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function CalculateArea(){
    var jari =document.form1.jari_jari.value;
    var luas_lingkaran = ("<P>Luas Lingkaran " + (jari * jari * Math.PI) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_lingkaran);
    var keliling_lingkaran = ("<P>Keliling lingkaran " + (2 * jari * Math.PI) + "</p>");
    document.write(keliling_lingkaran);
    var luas_persegi = ("<P>Luas Persegi " + (Math.pow(jari, 4)) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_persegi);
    var keliling_persegi = ("<p>Keliling Persegi " + (jari * 4) + "</p>");
    document.write(keliling_persegi);
    var luas_total = ("<p> Luas Persegi dan Lingkaran" + (luas_persegi + luas_lingkaran) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_total);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? What is your intended output and what are you getting actually?

Comment: because `luas_lingkaran` and `luas_persegi` are strings - you want `jari * jari * Math.PI + Math.pow(jari, 4)` - note: `document.write` is very 1990's way of doing things - I'm surprised any useful javascript tutorials even use it

Comment: I think keliling_lingkaran and keliling_persegi are strings. Need to take out the (jari * 4)  and (Math.pow(jari, 4)) expressions and assign each to a variable and add those variables.

Comment: You are adding strings which in JS is concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix for your code:

```
function CalculateArea(){
    var jari =document.form1.jari_jari.value;

    var luas_lingkaran = ("<p>Luas Lingkaran " + (jari * jari * Math.PI) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_lingkaran);

    var keliling_lingkaran = ("<p>Keliling lingkaran " + (2 * jari * Math.PI) + "</p>");
    document.write(keliling_lingkaran);

    var luas_persegi = ("<p>Luas Persegi " + (Math.pow(jari, 4)) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_persegi);

    var keliling_persegi = ("<p>Keliling Persegi " + (jari * 4) + "</p>");
    document.write(keliling_persegi);

    var luas_total = ("<p> Luas Persegi dan Lingkaran" + (Math.pow(jari, 4) + (jari * jari * Math.PI)) + "</p>");
    document.write(luas_total);
}
```

Notice the change in luas_total. You should use the actual calculations without any strings or text values.